# JQuery plugin working with width but not height

Tags: jquery, html

```
;(function($) {
            $.fn.textfill = function(options) {
                var fontSize = options.maxFontPixels;
                var ourText = $('span:visible:first', this);
                var maxHeight = $(this).height();
                var maxWidth = $(this).width();
                var textHeight;
                var textWidth;
                do {
                    ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
                    textHeight = ourText.height();
                    textWidth = ourText.width();
                    fontSize = fontSize - 1;
                } while ((textHeight > maxHeight || textWidth > maxWidth) && fontSize > 3);
                return this;
            }
        })(jQuery);
```

This is the plugin I'm using. When I call it on an element, it lessens the font size so it fits on one line in the `div` width wise, but it's not letting the text go onto the second line and fit height-wise as well. Both width and height are defined, I alerted them and saw them, so that's not the issue.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span does not have width or height in most browsers. It's just your particular browser being nice and letting you specify a height.

Change the span to a div and it should behave as expected...

Or actually, change the span to a block element

```
style="display:block;"
```

That should let you specify dimensions for the span

Comment: But I'm calling it on a div. The actual text is just in a span

Comment: your using it on the first span of the div. not the div itself.

Comment: Right but the plugin should be using the height of the outer div, not the span, which it seems to be doing, it's just not formatting for the height, only the width

Comment: var ourText = $('span:visible:first', this); bla bla...  textHeight = ourText.height(); Its picking up the height/width of the span. not sure how it decides to use the outer div?

Comment: Oh I was thinking the issue lied with maxHeight and maxWidth?